# Rspec verbose on fail within summary mode of large test suite

Tags: rspec

when we have a large test suite running, it will often fail in the early tests, but we still want to run the whole suite.

It would be great to see all the greens represented by their dot '.'
But, as well as F, for fail, it would be great to see the stacktrace or even just the line number of the error.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?
Cheers,
Ian.

Answer (score -1):

You are describing how RSpec works by default. You need extra options, like `--fail-fast` to make it stop at the first failure.

Maybe check your `.rspec` file if you don't have such options that change rspec behavior?

Comment: As described in the question, we do not need it to stop at the first fail, but display the fail, and continue. 

Thanks for your thoughts though.

Comment: Please read my answer again. What you want is a default rspec behavior. Did you check your .rspec file? Care to share what's there?